# VS2003 can't find .h file even after addition to "additional incl. dirs"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have file which needs to include blah.h in another project.  I've tried adding the directory that holds the blah.h file to

```
Project -> Project Properties -> Additional include directories
```

but I keep getting a "C1083: Cannot open include file: blah.h: No such file or directory".  I've tried absolute and relative paths to the folder housing blah.h with no success.

I'm using Visual Studios 2003. and my include statement looks like

```
#include "blah.h"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your "Additional include directories" property look like?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I won't have access to the computer with the code on it until Monday at which time I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the build (or at least this part of the build) working using:

```
#include "c:/path/to/blah.h"
```

If/when VS stops complaining about not being able to find `blah.h`, cut-n-paste the path used in the `#include` into the "Additional include directories".  Remember that the "Additional include directories" field should have the directories separated by a semi-colon.

Also, make sure that you set the "Additional include directories" property for all appropriate build configurations and platforms (drop-downs at the top of the Project property page dialog). Since the dialog opens up with only the "Active" configuration selected, I often find myself setting up an option for only the "Debug"/"Win32" configuration, then wonder for a second what's gone wrong when I get errors after switching to the "Release" configuration or "x64".

Comment: Thanks.  While this wasn't the direct solution, it helped me come up with the final solution (a redesign of the project structure).

Comment: @jok3maut: if it's not too much trouble, I think having your own answer (or even an edit to the question) describing the actual problem and solution would be good for anyone hitting on this in a search.

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this I use [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), a free utility from Microsoft.  Among other things, it logs accesses to files.  Filter on blah.h, see what path Visual Studio is really using, then adjust your "Additional Includes" as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here was my problem and the solution I came up with:

I have a multi-project solution in VS2003.  In one project I have a templated class **Child** defined in **Bar.h** which inherits from a non-templated class **Parent** in **Foo.h**.  **Parent** has a static member **some_mutex** declared in it.  This meant that I needed to define **some_mutex** in **Foo.cpp**.

The problem arose when I tried to include **Bar.h** in files in other projects, e.g. **other.vcproj**.  Without adding the include path to **Bar.h** in **other.vcproj** I'd get a C1083 error because the compiler couldn't find the definition for **Child**.  But when I added **Bar.h**'s include path to **other.vcproj** I'd get a LNK2001 error for **some_mutex** because **Foo.cpp** was in a different project and was not getting included/compiled.  This meant that **some_mutex** was undefined and that caused the LNK2001 error.

The solution was to put **Foo.h**, **Foo.cpp**, and **Bar.h** in their own project **NewProj** and create a static library.  The other projects that wanted to use the class **Child** just needed to include **NewProj.lib**, add the path to **NewProj.lib**, and add the include path to **Bar.h**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have entered the path to the "blah.h" directory as a relative path, be aware that VS2008 interprets those paths relative to the directory holding the .vcproj project file.  So you'll need to work out what that would be.

If your C++ file is "C:\myprogram\source\foo.cpp" and your include file is "C:\myprogram\includes\blah.h", it is not adequate to provide an include path of "..\includes".  You have to figure out where your project file is.  If it's "C:\myprogram\build\mysolution\myprogram\myprogram.vcproj" then the include path must be "..\..\..\includes".